# Dúvidas sobre escopo de bloco no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaração-de-variável, escopo-de-variáveis, scope

As dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Qual a diferença entre escopo de bloco e escopo de função no JavaScript?
- A ideia de escopo de bloco surgiu no EcmaScript 6 com `let` e `const`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Qual a diferença entre escopo de bloco e escopo de função no JavaScript?

A partir de ES6, usando `let` ou `const` é possível declarar variáveis que só existem dentro de blocos `{}`.

O exemplo mais comum é dentro de `if`, `for`, `try`,  `catch` mas também simplesmente:

```js
const foo = 123;
{
    // console.log(foo); // Erro, detecta a variável mas ainda não está declarada
    const foo = 456;
    console.log(foo); // 456
}
console.log(foo); // 123
```

Em JavaScript anterior a ES6 só existia `var` que não é sensível ao escopo de blocos e só respeita o escopo de funções. `let` e `const` respeitam o escopo de função e de bloco.

Sintetizando:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║                         ║   var      ║    let      ║    const    ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ pode ser sobre-escrita  ║     ✓      ║      ✓      ║      x      ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ escopo                  ║   funcão   ║    bloco    ║    bloco    ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ referenciável antes da  ║            ║             ║             ║
║ linha de declaração     ║     ✓      ║      x      ║      x      ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

> A ideia de escopo de bloco surgiu no EcmaScript 6 com let e const?

Sim, antes havia somente *"function scope"*

Answer (score 2):

Um escopo de bloco é aquele dentro de blocos de código `for`, `if else`, `try catch` entre outros:

```js
let foo = undefined;

try {
    let foo = 'foo';

    throw new Error();
} catch(e) {
    //foo === undefined
    console.log(foo);
} finally {
    //foo === undefined
    console.log(foo);
}

if (true) {
    let foo = 'foo';
}

//foo === undefined
console.log(foo);
```

As variáveis `let foo = 'foo';` só existem dentro dos respectivos blocos (`try` e `if`), nos blocos `catch`, `finally` e no escopo global a variável `foo` é referente a variável no escopo global `let foo = undefined;`

O escopo de funnção é igual, porém em vez de um bloco de código qualquer, é o bloco de uma função:

```js
let foo = undefined;

function bar() {
    var foo = 'foo';
}
bar();

//foo === undefined
console.log(foo);

const baz = () => {
    var foo = 'foo';
}
baz();

//foo === undefined
console.log(foo);

class Qux {
    constructor() {
        var foo = 'foo';
    }
}
new Qux();

//foo === undefined
console.log(foo);
```

Como pode ver todas variáveis `var foo = 'foo';` não existem fora da função, tanto tradicional como *arrow functions*, ou classe assim como nos exemplos anteriores em relação ao escopo de bloco

Não sei dizer se esse tipo de escopo surgiu com o ES6, mas antes dele não era possível, pelo menos não com JavaScript, talvez algo com TypeScript, CoffeScript ou algo assim