# Porque eu não consigo acessar a variável dentro de uma função?

Tags: javascript

```js
var n1 = 10;

if (n1 == 10) {
  var n2 = 45;
}

console.log(n2);
```

O exemplo acima funciona perfeitamente imprimindo o valor de `n2` no `console` do navegador nisso `n2` está dentro do comando `if` e está acessível, porém ao tentar pegar uma variável dentro de uma `function` ele não fica mais acessível e eu não consigo mais pegar o valor da variável `n2` e é retornado um erro (`Uncaught ReferenceError: n2 is not defined`).

```js
var n1 = 10;

function a() {
  var n2 = 45;
}

console.log(n2);
```

Minha pergunta é o porque de eu não consigo acessar a variável de uma `function`, mas do comando `if` eu consigo? desculpem a simplicidade do código, mas eu sou iniciante por completo, eu sai do *Portugol* e estou tentado aprender *JavaScript*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em JavaScript "antigo" é possível declarar funções dentro de um bloco, ou seja: `{}` e aceder essa variável declarada com `var` fora do bloco.

Isso não é possível em funções (nem em JavaScript antigo nem em moderno) pois a função cria um escopo próprio. Ou seja o que é declarado dentro da função fica dentro da função. Essa é uma das características de funções. Imagina caso isso não fosse assim a bagunça que seria em códigos grandes encontrar nomes para todas as variáveis que fosse único e problemas de segurança de poder aceder a todos os valores dentro de funçöes...

Com isso dito, [não deves mais usar `var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206121/129), em JavaScript moderno tens `let` e `const` que permitem [escopo de bloco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383294/129), ou seja: variáveis declaradas com `let` ou `const` dentro de blocos não são mais acessíveis fora dele.

```js
var n1 = 10;
let n3 = 33;

if (n1 == 10) {
  var n2 = 45;
  let n4 = 44;
}

console.log(n1, n2, n3); // 10 45 33
console.log(n4); // <- vai dar erro
```

Comment: então é só nas funções que é criado um escopo automaticamente no caso de outros comando não?

Comment: @draw no caso do `var`, sim

Comment: @guijob, valeu!