# Erro ao passar array como parâmetro de uma função. Uncaught TypeError: placas is undefined

Tags: javascript

Galera, estou fazendo um curso para aprender Javascript e já faz tempo que estou neste problema e não consigo entender o que acontece.

Eu preciso criar uma função que me permita contar quantas vezes uma das placas de carro aparece nesse array. Eu consigo executar normalmente quando não passo o parâmetro para a função, mas quando eu coloco o parâmetro e chamo a função eu recebo o erro **"Uncaught TypeError: placas is undefined"**, porém a variável placa está definida sim, talvez seja algo simples que deixei passar, não sei.

Sem passar o array placas como parâmetro:
[image: Sem passar o array placas como parâmetro:]

```js
<script>

var placas = [
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'
]


function calcularNumeroDeEntradas() {
  
   var cont = 0

 for(var i = 0; i<=placas.length;i++) { 
  
      if (placas[1] == [i]) {

         cont++; 
      }

}

return cont; 
}
```

Quando passo o array como parâmetro da função:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
<script>

var placas = [
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'
]


function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas) {
  
   var cont = 0

 for(var i = 0; i<=placas.length;i++) { 
  
      if (placas[1] == [i]) {

         cont++; 
      }

}

return cont; 
}
```

Comment: `function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas) {}` indica que você deve passar um parâmetro para poder acessar a função, ou seja, quando chamá-la, você deve a invocar da seguinte maneira: `var placas = ['...', '...']; calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas);`. Recomendo dar uma lida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383294/99718

Answer (score 0):

Chame sua função e passe placas como argumento: `calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas)`

Escopo em javascript no inicio é confuso. Escopo Global, de função de bloco. Mas com o tempo isso vai ficando claro e quando usar.

fonte: [Declaração de função](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

```js
var placas = [
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
    'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333',
    'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
    'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
    'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
    'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
    'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'
 ]

function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas) {
  let cont = 0;
  const plate = placas[1]
  for (var i = 0; i <= placas.length; i++) {
    if (plate == placas[i]) {
      cont++;
    }
  }

  return {plate, cont}
}

console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas))
```

Comment: Obrigado, Bruno!